# rpm's drop when stopped

Tags: ford, rough-idle, focus, stall

2000 SOHC automatic ford focus...new plugs wires coil pack oxygen sensor...IAC cleaned throttle sprayed with cleaner and seafoam used.....EGR checked. Car runs perfect except when I stop at lights (hold brake) starts fine although sometimes has a rough idle for a few minutes then normalizes...Any suggestions on what it could be.....Does have a code for misfire on 4 which I assume is from the rough idle/stalling

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Check for vacuum leaks on the intake manifold, hoses or gaskets.